# Get column Names of a procedure output using hibernate or JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to use JPA or hibernate for procedure calls to oracle database. The procedure gives a ref-cursor. I am making procedure calls using JPA (StoredProcedureQuery) but as I see I get only a list of data and not their column names.  I cannot map the result to any entity the procedure output is made up of at least 7 tables.
So is there any way where I can column names of the procedure output by either using JPA or hibernate?